# Factory based on input type

Tags: object-oriented

I'm trying to add specialized functionality to concrete types without adding the functionality directly to the interface of those concrete types.

Given a vehicle interface with 3 concrete types.

```
interface Vehicle {}
class Car implements Vehicle {}
class Motorcycle implements Vehicle {}
class Truck implements Vehicle {}
```

I have a component that creates vehicle reports. It has 3 different plans.

```
class VehicleReportingService {
  public void createBasicReport(Vehicle v){
    // get vehicle make and model
    // write report
  }

  public void createPlusReport(Vehicle v){
    // get vehicle make and model
    // get vehicle dimensions
    // write report
  }

  public void createPremiumReport(Vehicle v){
    // get vehicle make and model
    // get vehicle dimensions
    // get vehicle engine health
    // ... (more operations)
    // write report
  }
}
```

The operations like "get vehicle engine health" are complex so I want to add a new component for each operation instead of implementing them on the vehicles directly. The implementation is different for each vehicle type. For example there would be a separate component for each vehicle to check the engine health.

```
interface EngineHealthCheck {}
class CarEngineHealthCheck implements EngineHealthCheck {}
class MotorcycleEngineHealthCheck implements EngineHealthCheck {}
class TruckEngineHealthCheck implements EngineHealthCheck {}
```

One way to implement this would be to have a factory method on each vehicle type:

```
interface Vehicle {
  public EngineHealthCheck createEngineHealthCheck();
}
```

This list of operations can get quite long so I don't want to pollute the Vehicle interface with all those factories.

My current thinking is to add an auxiliary class which can contain all these factory methods.

```
interface VehicleInspectionModule {
  public EngineHealthCheck createEngineHealthCheck();
  // ... other inspection services
}
class CarInspectionModule implements VehicleInspectionModule {}
class MotorcycleInspectionModule implements VehicleInspectionModule {}
class TruckInspectionModule implements VehicleInspectionModule {}
```

And then require each `Vehicle` type to provide its own `VehicleInspectionModule`.

```
interface Vehicle {
  public VehicleInspectionModule createInspectionModule();
}
```

This way I can implement the reporting service like this.

```
class VehicleReportingService {
  // ...

  public void createPremiumReport(Vehicle v){
    VehicleInspectionModule vim = v.createInspectionModule();
    EngineHealthCheck ehc = vim.createEngineHealthCheck();
    EngineHealth eh = ehc.getEngineHealth();
    // ... (more operations)
    Report r = new Report();
    r.setEngineHealth(eh);
    r.write();
  }
}
```

This feels over-engineered but the system I'm working with has 100s of these checks that can be called in different permutations.

Does anyone think there is a better way to solve this?

Comment: Now you've just "polluted" VehicleInspectionModule with factory methods, haven't you? I think the #1 rule here is to not overcomplicate things for no benefit.

Comment: Yeah. I'm ok with that. Vehicle is used in a lot of places whereas VehicleInspectionModule is only used by my team.

Comment: I guess I just don't see the advantage instead of `EngineHealth eh = v.getEngineHealth();`. (By the way, what will you do when some vehicles don't have some report types? what is the engine health of a bicycle?)

Comment: Looks like what you're describing here is the Go4 Abstract Factory pattern - your vehicle inspection module is the abstract factory, that then serves to "create a family of related products" - your different kinds of checks; the vehicle decides on the concrete factory. Without a deeper understanding of your problem domain, no one can really tell you if that's overengineered or not, but that said, having 100s of methods on the inspection module doesn't feel quite right - if that's what you were saying. In any case, you seem to not like this solution, and maybe your gut feeling is right. 1/2

Comment: Now, a couple of things to consider. Which are you more likely to add - new kinds of operations or new kinds of vehicles? 'Cause, generally speaking, you can't make both kinds of extensibility equally smooth. This should affect how you approach the problem. Can you find some common abstraction that's more universal than your vehicles - e.g. some data structure that you can pass to your calculations that can be the same for each vehicle; if you can, than that could reduce the number of parallel hierarchies you have. In other words, try and see if there is a way to reformulate the problem. 2/2